# How to check if a 4-pin button is burnt out?

Tags: wiring, multimeter, short-circuit, button, test-equipment

I was soldering a circuit with a 4-pin button in it and was trying to find a janky connection. I had the button output displayed via serial terminal (since the circuit used an Arduino) while I was fixing it, and it was sporadically returning "HIGH", just not when I wanted to. However, while I was fixing, the output suddenly turned to 0 and would not go back to HIGH whatever I did.

I'm trying to figure out whether this is an issue with connection or soldering, or whether I'd short circuited the button and burnt it out. However, since the button has 4 pins, how would I test it with a multimeter?

Below is how the button is set up, there are other components in the circuit but those work perfectly and don't interfere with the button at all. Essentially, one leg of the button is connected to 5V, one leg is connected to a 10k resistor, which is then connected to ground. A third leg, vertical to the resistor, is connected to a digital pin of the Arduino (I am using a Nano Every, not the Uno shown here):

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo what you are actually doing, instead of idealized diagram how it should be done? And post also the code you use to initialize and read the pin.

Comment: turn the switch body 1/4 turn in either direction and test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four legs on those buttons but two are connected together internally on each side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faU3Mh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A PCB momentary button pinout.*

Disconnect the wires and use a multimeter to figure out which pins are connected and which are connected when the button is pressed.

Comment: I tested using a multimeter before I soldered it, so I know which pins are connected and which aren't. The problem is I'm not sure how to test since I don't know if the button is broken/burnt out--would there be different multimeter outputs then?

Comment: Yes, as described in my answer, use the meter's continuity function to test. If all four pins are connected all the time then the button is permanently "closed". If you get an open-circuit then press the button and you should get a beep.

Comment: @RenaW You could try unplugging the 5V (it will interfere with the measurement), set your multimeter to beep mode, and hold one probe on each side of the button (one on the left, one on the right as the drawing is drawn). If it beeps and you're not pressing the button, the button is broken. If you can't get it to beep, maybe look for other problems, e.g., maybe the resistor is loose? (these breadboards sometimes don't make good connections)

Comment: @Transistor Other way around. See how the legs stick out the top and bottom of the button? Those are two pieces of metal that go all the way through the button.

Comment: @RenaW, I forgot to mention that the switch should be isolated (no connections) before doing the test.

Comment: @user253751. You are correct. Comment being deleted! 3, 2, 1 ...

Comment: I see--I will test and see what happens, thank you!